# Possible to set default schema from connection string?

Tags: sql-server, schema, connection-string

With SQL Server 2005 and 2008 is it possible to set the default schema from the connection string? It'd be a lot easier if we didn't have to manually set the schema with SQL code.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

No, this is done at the database User level, not in the connection string.

For reference, here are all of the properties which can be set in a connection string: https://www.connectionstrings.com/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords/

Answer (score 43):

You set the default schema based on the user who is logging in via the connection, not the connection itself.

```
ALTER USER Mary51 WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = Purchasing;
```

Reference:

- [ALTER USER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx)

Comment: That would really suck for us though :/

Comment: LMAO..I posted exactly the same thing  :-)

Comment: You mean you both came up with mary5 as a random name? Noway!

Comment: A very good idea. But is it possible to do this in AWS Redshift?

Answer (score 13):

change the default schema associated with that login

example

```
ALTER USER Mary51 WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = Purchasing;
```

More detail here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx

Answer (score 2):

*If when you say "Schema," you mean "Owner" (i.e. dbo), then I believe the selected answer is correct.*

*However, if you mean "Database" instead, which in some vendor's lingo means the same thing as "Schema," then I have provided some more info below.*

In the link that TimS provided:

- [All SQL Server SqlConnection properties](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords)

Scroll down to the row with these two properties:

> Initial Catalog -or- Database

Here's an example connection string with a *DEFAULT DATABASE*:

```
Server=myServerName\myInstanceName,1433;Database=DEFAULT_DATABASE;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

See link below for more examples:

- [Connection strings for SQL Server 2012](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012)

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem too.
I removed `Integrated Security=sspi;` from my connection string and then it worked fine.