# How to specify schema name in connectionstring in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, connection-string, database-schema

How can I specify a schema name in SQL ConnectionString using ASP.net dynamically.
I have a single database with multiple schema. I need to fetch data from table belonging to particular schema.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only specify the database and user details in the connection string.

To retrieve data from a specific schema, you need to reference that schema in your query. For example;

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM [Schema].[Table]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to reference here an older thread, which is definitely useful in this question:

[Possible to set default schema from connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282665/possible-to-set-default-schema-from-connection-string)

You can only set the default schema to the user itself. 
You can try an [ALTER USER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx) statement, where you can define a default schema to the user.
It means you can create a user to each schema, if that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Each user has their own schema and that is the default schema. Once logged in you can execute:

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = myschema
```

So you need to execute an extra statement after connecting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it. I just tried it.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"<Connection Name>": "Host=<Database Server>;Database=<Database Name>;Port=5432;Username=<WindowUserName>;Password=<WindowsPassword>;IntegratedSecurity=true;SearchPath=MySchema"
```