# Servicestack Multi Tenancy

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Does the [Servicestack](http://docs.servicestack.net/) support the Single Deployment with Single Database multi-tenancy method? [The documentation says only about multiple databases](http://docs.servicestack.net/multitenancy).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multi-tenancy is centered around having different connection strings per tenant but you could potentially override `GetDbConnection(IRequest)` in your AppHost to [change the Users schema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3282682/85785) on DB Connection for each request.

Comment: you mean, having multiple schemas for each tenant. Am I correct?  As I have read, a multi-tenancy system can have Single Deployment - Multiple Database or Single Deployment - Single Database or Single Deployment - Hybrid Databases).  I need to implement a system with Single Deployment - Single Database.

Comment: I've not tried single database myself but I expect you should be able to get it working with multiple schemas, potentially you could also get shared database, shared schema to work if you set the Session Context for the User Id when you open the connection as done in the [EF shared db, shared user example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-entity-framework-row-level-security).