# Create (virtually) multiple databases under one AWS Redshift instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

We are using AWS RDS Postgres at the moment and are thinking of shifting to AWS Redshift.

## Problem

We want to create two databases (1 for STAGING, 1 for PRODUCTION) under it but we came to know that we can only create ONE database under an instance.

## Research

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3282682/10190191) answer which said that I can create multiple schemas and then simply set the default schema for roles that way I can virtually achieve different databases for PROD and QA and I will not have to change any of my queries.
But while reading the developer [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/redshift-dg.pdf), at page 382 I read that `DATABASE ROLES` is listed under `Unsupported PostgreSQL Features`.

## Question

How can I achieve this functionality given my use case in AWS Redshift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Redshift you can create multiple databases within one cluster. (max of around 60)

the command

```
create database newdbname;
```

will do this.

Any one query can ONLY access one database at a time so correct permissions can be set up per database.

So, I think you have everything you need.

ref:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Privileges.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_DATABASE.html

Comment: yes u r right, devops guy must be mistaken should've seen myself. Thanks.