# EF Core migration System.InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a solution with 5 projects:

- API
- Contract
- Entities
- Services
- Tests

When creating the migration I had the same problem:

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext

I succeed to create it by using --startup-project in the command

Now I tried to run the migration with the following command

```
PM> dotnet ef database update
```

I got

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext.

In `program.cs` I have

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
 options =>
 { options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
 });
```

My `ApplicationDbContext` is as follow:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base()
    {
    }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
     : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Episode> Episodes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductTimeline> ProductTimelines { get; set; }
    public DbSet<QuizzQuestion> QuizzQuestions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<QuizzQuestionTimeline> QuizzQuestionTimelines { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

I run the command in the Package Manager Console and I set the default project to `Entities`. I try to run it with the API project selected
I still get the error.

Please help

===============================
Following Qing Guo suggestion, I modify my ApplicationDbContext
When I run the Update command it work
I still do not understand what was wrong with my original ApplicationDbContext.

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at the code proposed in [The default schema does not exist EF Core Migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77443534/the-default-schema-does-not-exist-ef-core-migration/77443749#77443749) if it could help you. It refers to [Design-time DbContext Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try this ?

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
 {
  public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
 : base(options)
  {
  }

public DbSet<Episode> Episodes { get; set; }
public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
public DbSet<ProductTimeline> ProductTimelines { get; set; }
public DbSet<QuizzQuestion> QuizzQuestions { get; set; }
public DbSet<QuizzQuestionTimeline> QuizzQuestionTimelines { get; set; }


}
```