# DbConnectionProvider for ELMAH

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, connection-string, elmah

I would like to use ELMAH in ASP.NET MVC3 project. I used nuget install package and install ELMAH. 
It configure itself in config file, with connection string.

Question:
It propose to define connection string in config file. but I can not define connection string in config file and connection string dynamicaly produce with custom connection provider factory when application start.
How can I set connection string or DbConnection for ELMAH?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [How to use EntityFramework connection string for Elmah?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083558/how-to-use-entityframework-connection-string-for-elmah)

Essentially you need to create your own ErrorLog implementation (inherit from SqlErrorLog) and override the `ConnectionString` property.

Comment: hi Ben, I saw linked question and I wrote this answer also. thanks you remembered me.